# How to move line up in Mac for Sublime Text?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3, sublimetext

On OS X when I use the shortcut provided in documentation (`⌘ + ⌃ + Up` which I read as `Command + Shift + Up`) Sublime Text selects the text instead of moving the line up. Am I missing something?

Comment: Looking at [this](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_osx.html) it might be that they mean the `^` character and not the key shift. Below they have another symbol (⇧) which looks more like shift to me.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

According to https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_osx.html, it should be <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>.

- ⌘ = <kbd>Command</kbd>
- ⇧ = <kbd>Shift</kbd>
- ⌥ = <kbd>Option</kbd> (a.k.a. <kbd>Alt</kbd>)
- ⌃ = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
- ⎋ = <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- ↩︎ = <kbd>Return</kbd>
- ⌫ = <kbd>Delete</kbd> (a.k.a. <kbd>Backspace</kbd>)

See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42615/is-there-a-list-of-menu-shortcut-icons for the meaning of the symbols.

Answer (score 17):

I could not track down what was causing the key binding collision, so I set user key bindings in Sublime Text to an alternative. To do this, open Sublime Text. In the top menu navigate to Sublime Text > Preferences > Key Bindings then add these hashes to the array with the alternative key binding of your choice:

```html
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+super+up"], "command": "swap_line_up" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+super+down"], "command": "swap_line_down" },
]
```

Answer (score 5):

"control" + "cmd" + up  (in Mac)

Answer (score 4):

- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>

In a Visual Studio Code, configured with Sublime Text Keymaps, you can also use:

- <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>

Comment: Option + Up won't move the line up